# What is the difference between Assumption and Assertion?

Tags: differences, synonyms

How does assume differs from assert?

Looking for a explanation with an example statement for both (it's better if the example statements are in the same context).

Comment: I ***assume*** you haven't compared the dictionary definitions of the two words. I ***assert*** that the distinction is obvious, so I'm closevoting for lack of evidence of prior research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically,

assume: it's about **thinking** something

Any good dictionary has examples, and so has this one:

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/assume

assert: it's about **saying/stating** something

http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/assert

Answer (score 0):

To **assume** is to believe something without having definite proof, in its primary sense. To **assert** is to state that something is so.

For example: "Constable Brown asserted that the young man was a thief. I assumed that he was telling the truth,  because he is a policeman."  Here, the speaker has based his assumption on the constable's job.